# Using styles to manipulate WPF buttons, but selectively

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, styles, custom-controls

I have a few button controls in my WPF Window, they all have their purpose but need to be styled differently according to their meaning/task.
I know using styles you can globally style buttons using `TargetType`.

**But what if I wanted to style buttons selectively?**

Calculator example: Some buttons represent a number, others represent a function, like Adding, Dividing. So lets say I want the numbers buttons to be green, the function buttons to be blue.

My approach would have been to inherit from `Button` and make custom button controls, `NumberButton`, `FunctionButton`, and then use `<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:NumberButton}">` etc.

Is there a better approach that is less of a "hack"? Can this be done selectively in the style definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about using `DataTriggers` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep everything in one implicit `Style` then one solution could be to use `Tag` property of a `Button` and `Trigger` different setters on different values

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:NumberButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="GreenBackground">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

where you button would be

```
<my:NumberButton Tag="GreenBackground"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your tag "GreenBackground" be called "NumberButton" or anything that makes abstraction more obvious ?

Comment: you can trigger on any `Tag` value and this is just an example to show the idea

Answer (score 0):

When using `Style`s in WPF, we can declare them to be applied implicitly by *not declaring an `x:Key` value*:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type SomeType}">
    ...
</Style>
```

This will be implicitly applied to all controls of type `SomeType`. `Style`s can also be declared to be applied explicitly by *declaring an `x:Key` value*:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type SomeType}">
    ...
</Style>
```

...

```
<SomeType Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}" />
```

This `SomeStyle` will only be applied to this one control. Please see the [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms742804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your styles prevents them from being applied "globally":

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NumberButton" TargetType={x:Type Button}/>
    <Style x:Key="FunctionButton" TargetType={x:Type Button}/>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can now style your buttons the way you want by referencing to the name of the specific style in each Button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NumberButton}"/>
```